# AssetNotFoundException in SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

I'm actually trying to make program that is displaying some picture on the Window
Here is part of code

```
public Texture2D tulTexture;
//...
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch
    spriteBatch = ToDisposeContent(new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice));

    // Loads the balls texture (32 textures (32x32) stored vertically => 32 x 1024 ).
    // The [Balls.dds] file is defined with the build action [ToolkitTexture] in the project
    tulTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("T.jpg");

    // Loads a sprite font
    // The [Arial16.xml] file is defined with the build action [ToolkitFont] in the project


    base.LoadContent();
}
```

When I'm running the program,I'm getting the AssetNotFoundException but this is lie.I've got this asset!

Comment: Please post the full StackTrace.

Comment: I ran into the same problem a while back. It was helpful to step into the SharpDX code and watch it build the path to the file that it was trying to open.

I've also seen this from not setting the correct build action for the image file - it needs to be ToolkitTexture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > AssetNotFoundException but this is lie.I've got this asset!

It is most likely that you didn't configure your texture to be part of the build. You need to set the action "ToolkitTexture" on the texture in VS, and read the texture `Content.Load<Texture2D>("T")` without the ".jpg", as it is done in SharpDX samples. This is explained in the comment of the code above you pasted.